# The '?' character cannot be used here

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, nullable

With these variables:

```
Dim d1 As Date? = Nothing
Dim d2 As DateTime? = Nothing
Dim i1 As Integer? = Nothing
Dim i2 As Int32? = Nothing
```

Why am I allowed to do this?:

```
Dim flag1 As Boolean = Date?.Equals(d1, d2)
Dim flag2 As Boolean = Integer?.Equals(i1, i2)
```

...but not allowed to do this?:

```
Dim flag3 As Boolean = DateTime?.Equals(d2, d1)
Dim flag4 As Boolean = Int32?.Equals(i2, i1)
```

The last code will fail with an error saying:

> *The '?' character cannot be used here.*

Comment: Can anyone reproduce this?

Comment: Reproduced in VS2013 also. The issue seems to be that it's fine with it when you're using a language keyword for the type name, but not when you're actually referencing the .NET framework type name (implicitly, from the `System` namespace). Note the different way that the types are highlighted.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think you are correct. I can do `Single?.Equals(0.0!, 0.0!)` but not `System.Single?.Equals(0!, 0!)`.

Comment: Yes, I did a similar test of `Char` vs `System.Char` :-)

Comment: Well then consequently you can only do classes that vb considers as  elemental :)

Comment: if you hit SHift-F2 to go to the definition in Object Browser, `Int32? `takes you to `System` while `Integer` takes you to `Nullable(Of T)`.  So VS seems to 'see' them as different somehow or that the use of `?` is only partially recognized.

Comment: I've gone back and forth through the VB language spec several times and I can't find anywhere where any difference in the handling of primitive types vs other value types is called for.

Comment: I have VS 2008 here (urg) and I can reproduce your problem. I would suggest to not use ? in VB, I think it doesn't do what you expect. Use Nullable(Of ), that's sort of the VB way of doing it.

Comment: @the_lotus - the language spec appears to say otherwise: "the type `T?` is synonymous to the type `System.Nullable(Of T)`, and the two names can be used interchangeably" - that's what has many of us confused.

Comment: It is a parser quirk.  `Integer` is a keyword, not a type identifier.  And Integer? is valid in variable declarations so a valid keyword as well.  Doesn't work on Int32 since it is not a keyword.

Comment: I still cannot do this in VS2019: `Dim MyUserID As String = MyUser?.UserID`  even though MS says it should be possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators   Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB.NET developers are not supposed to be using C# keywords (religion, you know). Seriously though, I agree with @Konrad this looks like a compiler bug. If you have other VS, try it there, I only tried in VS 2010 SP1, cause that's what I have at work. If you notice consistency, perhaps you should report it on [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/). As a workaround, you can try this:

```
Dim flag3 As Boolean = d1.Equals(d1)
Dim flag4 As Boolean = i2.Equals(i1)
```

Or this:

```
Dim flag3 As Boolean = Nullable(Of DateTime).Equals(d1, d2)
Dim flag4 As Boolean = Nullable(Of Int32).Equals(i1, i2)
```

I personally prefer the last option in my code, to explicitly say `Nullable(Of T)`, because VB language is supposed to be verbose, more English-like, i.e. no `:? || &&` constructs (no offense, C# devs).

Comment: I have just encountered this bug on VS2010, but what I was trying is something like `if (a?.b?.c?.d is nothing) then`, is there a work around for this other than using `AndAlso` this way: `if (a is nothing andalso b is nothing...)` etc...